# Binary tree- count number of nodes in a complete binary tree

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

I am to count number of nodes in a complete binary tree.I know one way to do this using **recursion** and my code looks like this

```
class Solution {
public:
 int countNodes(TreeNode* root) {
    if(!root)return 0;
    int sz;
    sz=1+countNodes(root->left)+countNodes(root->right);
    return sz;
  }
};
```

But it is giving me **Time Limit Exceed** in an online judge.Maybe in case of skewed binary tree.

How to do this more efficiently ?

**P.S:**  I also tried BFS but no luck.

Comment: Please supply the structure and invocation that run this out of time.
The logic looks fine, so I suspect some interaction problem.
We really need to have *everything* to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (from your intro tour) for StackOverflow expectations.

Comment: @Prune Hi :) I was able to get the logic.It is complete binary tree so every level is completely filled except last so we just need to calculate number of leaf nodes and rest is trivial :)

Comment: If it's a complete, level, balanced binary tree, it's even easier: do a depth-first search on one branch to get the depth, N.  The tree then has 2^N - 1 total nodes.